# Checking if variable is a certain value

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I want to check if the user input is equal to a certain value

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
    SetConsoleCP(1252);

    char meningen[100];



    printf("Hello \n");
    printf("I want you to write 'Simon Anderson'.\n");

    scanf(" %[^\n]s", meningen);
        if (meningen == "Simon Anderson")
        {
            printf("Congratilation. You have won the game.\n");
            printf("Have a good day");

        }
        else {
            printf("You failed.\n");

        }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is whatever I write I still get the "You failed" printed out. How can I make it so it returns true if the user wrote as the value in the if-statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (meningen == "Simon Anderson")
```

should be

```
if (strcmp(meningen,"Simon Anderson") ==0)
```

I suggest you to use

```
fgets(meningen,sizeof(meningen),stdin);
```

instead of scanf() as `fgets()` takes care of buffer overflow and also make a note that `fgets()` comes with a newline character. You need to remove the newline character as shown below.

```
size_t n = strlen(meningen);
if(n>0 && a[n-1] == '\n')
a[n-1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working because you are comparing a string with `==`:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", meningen);
if (meningen == "Simon Anderson")
```

This is comparing the *address of* the `meningen` array, rather than the value(s) it contains. To check the *contents* of the array, you should use the [`strcmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) function instead:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", meningen);
if (strcmp(meningen, "Simon Anderson") == 0)
```